# Upgrading postgresql 9.6.0 to 9.6.1. What does "update binaries" mean?

Tags: windows, postgresql

I have a postgresql 9.6.0 (bigsql) installed in a Windows 10 Pro machine (development station) and wish to update to 9.6.1, recently released.

I will later upgrade the Windows 2012 Server installation of the same Postgres version as well, so if the instructions are portable to the Windows 2012 server, this will be a double-kill shot.

Postgres documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1712/) states that I "may simply shut down PostgreSQL and update its binaries."

I have downloaded the binaries but wish to know which folders should I copy to the  ""C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL" or "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\pg96" , being "\96" the name of the instance.

---

```
    Folder C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL
    2016-09-13  16:19              bam2
    2016-10-28  08:43              conf
    2016-10-14  17:17              data
    2016-10-05  16:36              hub
    2016-04-01  01:31              java8
    2016-10-05  16:51              logs
    2016-10-13  14:23              pg96
    2016-09-27  09:34             1.886 pgc.bat
    2016-09-01  09:57              pgstudio2
    2016-10-05  16:39              python2
    2016-10-13  14:24              uninstall

    Folder C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\pg96
    2016-09-27  09:35               725 activity-pg96.py
    2016-10-05  16:39              bin
    2016-09-27  09:35             7.044 config-pg96.py
    2016-09-27  09:35             1.054 create_service.bat
    2016-10-05  16:37              include
    2016-10-05  16:36              init
    2016-09-27  09:35             4.798 init-pg96.py
    2016-10-05  16:39              lib
    2016-10-13  14:23               351 pg96-env.bat
    2016-09-27  09:35           103.936 pgservice.exe
    2016-09-27  09:35           104.448 pgservicew.exe
    2016-09-27  09:35               551 reload-pg96.py
    2016-09-27  09:35               714 remove-pg96.py
    2016-09-27  09:35             1.237 run-pgctl.py
    2016-10-05  16:36              share
    2016-09-27  09:35             2.145 start-pg96.py
    2016-09-27  09:35             1.837 stop-pg96.py
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Here are the downloaded binaries
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Folder C:\Softwares\postgres\postgresql-9.6.1-1-windows-x64-binaries\pgsql
    2016-10-27  17:02              bin
    2016-10-27  17:12              doc
    2016-10-27  17:11              include
    2016-10-27  17:15              lib
    2016-10-27  17:06              pgAdmin 4
    2016-10-27  17:03              share
    2016-10-27  17:12              StackBuilder
    2016-10-27  17:15              symbols
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am from BigSQL Development team.
Upgrading to latest minor version is simple.

1. Take a command prompt as Administrator
2. Go to the directory where you installed.
   in your case it is : C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL
3. Issue "pgc update" to get the metadata information about latest versions.
4. Issue "pgc upgrade pg96" to upgrade to lastest minor version available.

Hope this helps.